# MIlitary Time Validating

Tags: java

I want to make sure that there are 5 characters in what the user inputs to change it to a military time and pretty much this is the format `##:##` (with the colon as well) and this is part of my code, but I cannot make it work.

Any help will be great - thanks.

```
public Time(String militaryTime)
{
    //Check to make sure something was entered
    if (militaryTime == null || !militaryTime.matches("^\\d{2}:\\d{2}$"))
    {
        System.out.println(
            "You must enter a valid miliary time." );
    }
    //Check to make sure there are 5  characters
    else
    {
        //Check to make sure the colon is in the right spot

        if (!Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(2)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        //Check to make sure all other characters are digits
        else if (!Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (!Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (!Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (!Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else
        {
            //this separates hours and minutes
            hours = Integer.parseInt(militaryTime.substring(0,2));

            //validate hours and minutes are valid values
            if(hours > 23)
            {
                System.out.println(militaryTime +
                    " is not a valid miliary time." );
            }
            else if(minutes > 59)
            {
                System.out.println(militaryTime +
                    " is not a valid miliary time." );
            }
            //convert military time to conventional time
            //for afternoon times
            else if (hours > 12)
            {
                hours = hours - 12;
                afternoon = true;
                System.out.println(this.toString());
            }
            //account for midnight
            else if (hours == 0)
            {
                hours = 12;
                System.out.println(this.toString());
            }
            //account for noon
            else if (hours == 12)
            {
                afternoon = true;
                System.out.println(this.toString());
            }
            //morning times don't need converting
            else
            {
                System.out.println(this.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see what the military has to do with this. It seems you are talking about a standard 24 hour time format.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock
"It is popularly referred to as military time in the United States, English-speaking Canada, and a handful of other countries where the 12-hour clock is still dominant."

Comment: @SkinnyJ: Really? Sounds strange to me...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its just the military format lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way in most languages is to use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
if (militaryTime == null || !militaryTime.matches("^\\d{2}:\\d{2}$")) {
    System.out.println(militaryTime + " is not a valid military time.");
}
```

This will not check that the hour is between 0-24 or that the minute is between 0-60, but your code doesn't appear to care either.

Alternately you can use the [Java time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
try {
   DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").parse(militaryTime)
}
catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
   System.out.println(militaryTime + " is not a valid military time.");
}
```

This will verify that it's fully compliant.

Comment: I edited and posted the code but still when i enter the time as  ##:## it does not run properly? any thoughts on this current messy code?

Comment: @xTuckii it's completely unclear what you are asking now. The question was how to ensure that a `String` is of format ##:## where ## are 2 digits. I've answered that question. "It does not run properly" is not a question.

Comment: sorry about that, my question is why even after i input the ##:## format on the running program it keeps on saying  that is not a valid military time.

Comment: @xTuckii you'll need to debug your code. I would strongly recommend replacing all the if/else statements with regular expressions, or parse it into [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). That will make it the easiest to work with.

Comment: I changed my if/else statements, it work perfect! I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 public static boolean isMilitoryTmeString(String militaryTime) {
            // Check to make sure something was entered
            if (militaryTime == null) {
                return false;
            }
            // Check to make sure there are 5 characters
            if (militaryTime.length() != 5) {

                return false;
            }

            // Storing characters into char variable 
            char hourOne = militaryTime.charAt(0);
            char hourTwo = militaryTime.charAt(1);
            char colon = militaryTime.charAt(2);
            char minuteOne = militaryTime.charAt(3);
            char minuteTwo = militaryTime.charAt(4);

            //first position of hour must be 0 or 1 or 2
            if (hourOne != '0' && hourOne != '1' && hourOne != '2') {

                return false;
            }
            //if first position of hour is 0 or 1 then second
            //position must be 0-9
            if (hourOne == '0' || hourOne == '1') {

                if (hourTwo < '0' || hourTwo > '9') {
                    return false;
                }

            //if hourOne equal 2 then second position must be 0-3
            } else {

                if (hourTwo < '0' || hourTwo > '3') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
           //third position must be colon
            if (colon != ':') {

                return false;
            }
            // fourth position must be 0-5
            if (minuteOne < '0' || minuteOne > '5') {
                return false;
            }

            //fifth position must be 0-9
            if (minuteTwo < '0' || minuteTwo > '9') {
                return false;
            }
            // String is valid military time
            return true;
        }
```